# Does C# stores references to tasks from TPL

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

Lets assume I run such a code

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(...).ContinueWith(...);
```

I don't store reference for neither of two created tasks so can I be sure that they won't be disposed before starting or at the process of executing? If yes then where do reference to these tasks are being held?

Comment: You can find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782802/can-net-task-instances-go-out-of-scope-during-run

Comment: Short answer is yes, of course.  Will be interesting to see if someone can explain in more detail of course :)

Comment: They will NOT be disposed at all. They may be garbage collected, but they wont be disposed. The garbage collector does NOT call `Dispose()` on `IDisposable` objects. You MUST explicitly call `Dispose()` yourself.

Comment: Actually I meant 'Garbage collected' instead of 'Disposed'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A reference to  a TPL `Task` is held by the system under two conditions:

1. The Task is scheduled
2. The Task is running

Upon completion of the `Task` and any child tasks, the reference is thrown away. References in your code will behave as expected.

---

I believe you have some confusion regarding garbage collection and `Dispose`. This question may enlighten you.

> [Difference between destructor, dispose and finalize method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988334/difference-between-destructor-dispose-and-finalize-method)
>
> Destructor implicitly calls the Finalize method, they are technically same. Dispose is available with those object which
> implements IDisposable interface...

**Should you dispose Tasks?**

Stephen Toub says:

> No.  Don’t bother disposing of your tasks.
>
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/

Comment: But `Dispose` wont be called unless the finalizer explicitly calls it and there is no guarantee that the finalizer will actually run.

Comment: @Enigmativity This article should help you out on that point http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/25/10287435.aspx

Comment: I actually meant 'Garbage collected' instead of 'Disposed'

Comment: @Gusdor - Thanks for the link, but it does change the widespread misconception that the garbage collector calls `Dispose()`. That was my point.

Comment: *"A reference to a TPL Task is held by the system under two conditions: 1. The Task is scheduled, 2. The Task is running"* <== Do you mean that both conditions must be true, or that at least one must be true?

Comment: @Gusdor The link you have shared in both the post and the comment is broken. The blog is [Do I need to dispose of Tasks?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/)

Comment: Thanks for that @ghd. I've updated the answer with the correct link.