# Can working infinite unreferenced Task be garbage collected?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, task, task-parallel-library

If I have a code like:

```
public static void Main() 
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        while (true)
        {
            DoSomethingVeryImportant();
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

    Console.WriteLine("Started.");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Closing.");
}
```

Is there a chance that this task will be finalized since there are no references to it?
Will `var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(...` solve the problem?

I understand that in this specific case it would be better to use local `task` variable, `CancellationToken`, cancel the task and wait for it to end, but now I am curious about the other thing - the behaviour of GC towards unreferenced `Task`.

Comment: Create a `WeakReference<Task>`, then call `GC.Collect()` and see if it is collected or not.

Comment: Have a look at [Does C# stores references to tasks from TPL [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23133209/8098743) and [Can .NET Task instances go out of scope during run?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2782993/8098743). This should give you an answer.